# TemplateDoesNotExist exception

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django. I am facing an exception TemplateDoesNotExist at /.
I guess there is some problem with my template DIR.

**Here is the URL:**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from first_app import views

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Here is the view:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    my_dict={'insert_me':"Hello I have created my first dynamic Template"}
    return render(request,'Twenty3rdMarch/first_app/templates/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

**Here is my Settings:**

```py
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
print(TEMPLATES_DIR)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Twenty3rdMrach.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Twenty3rdMrach.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'udemy',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'Ravi@go123',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Please help me out to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Twenty3rdMarch/first_app/templates/index.html` to `index.html`. You don't need full path when referencing templates from `APP_DIRS`.

However I suggests you to namespace your templates dirs properly. Simply putting `index.html` in app's template dir can cause template overriding. You should create directory inside app's template dir with same name like this.

```
myapp
  templates
    myapp
      index.html
```

and then reference it like `myapp/index.html`

For more information, please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory) doc.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the templates folder under your main project's folder and make this change to your `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    -----rest of settings ------
}]
```